# SQL query excluding specific values for the same column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to generate a project progress report which consists in pretty much checking the % of completed milestones within a given timeframe.
(e.g: Company A had 10 due milestones by today, but marked only 8 as completed, therefore they are progressing 20% slower than planned.)

This part easy and it is working great, however before generating it, I have a determine if a project plan is approved or not. An approved project plan is the one with milestones 1 and 2 = 100.

Below you can see the table structure I have to work with.

```
ID          Company     Project     Milestone   Date        Completion
170825240   Company A   Project 1   Milestone 1 29.10.12    100
170825311   Company A   Project 1   Milestone 2 29.10.12    0
170825242   Company A   Project 1   Milestone 3 05.11.12    100
170825173   Company A   Project 1   Milestone 4 17.12.12    0
170825104   Company B   Project 1   Milestone 1 29.10.12    100
170825035   Company B   Project 1   Milestone 2 29.10.12    100
170824966   Company B   Project 1   Milestone 3 05.11.12    100
170824897   Company B   Project 1   Milestone 4 17.12.12    0
170824828   Company C   Project 1   Milestone 1 29.10.12    100
170824759   Company C   Project 1   Milestone 2 29.10.12    100
170824690   Company C   Project 1   Milestone 3 05.11.12    0
170824621   Company C   Project 1   Milestone 4 17.12.12    0
```

In this snapshot, project 1 is approved for the companies B and C.

The issue I am facing is how to combine in a single query progress filtering  the approved plans only. I would hate to write the exceptions manually, since we are talking about 1600 combinations for company and projects.

Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Thanks!!!!

UPDATED

```
SELECT S1.[Company], COUNT(S1.[Milestone]) AS ShouldBeMilestones

FROM Sheet1 AS S1

INNER JOIN Sheet1 S2
ON S2.[Company] = S1.[Company]
AND S2.[Project] = S1.[Project]
AND S2.[Milestone] = 'Milestone 1'
AND S2.[%compl#] = 100

INNER JOIN Sheet1 S3
ON S3.[Company] = S1.[Company]
AND S3.[Project] = S1.[Project]
AND S3.[Milestone] = 'Milestone 2'
AND S3.[%compl#] = 100

WHERE ((S1.[Task class] <> 'A') AND (S1.[Task class] <> 'B') AND (S1.[Task class] <> ''))
AND S1.[Milestone] NOT LIKE '0.*' AND S1.[Milestone] NOT LIKE '1.*'
AND S1.[Start] <= Now()

GROUP BY S1.[Company];
```

Comment: A bit offtopic, but do you have situation, where milestone2=100, but milestone1<100? If not, then it is enough to check for milestone2 only :)

Comment: Thanks Arvo. Very good point! We must check both because they are owned by different stakeholders. Actually M2 would be enough, but we have seen some situations in which the M2 is 100 but the M1 not. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is also possible with joins borrowing from the previous answer ;)

```
select m.* 
(from    Milestones m
inner join Milesones as m1 
      on m1.Company = m.Company
      and m1.Project = m.Project
      and m1.Milestone = 'Milestone 1'
      and m1.Completion = 100)
inner join Milestones as m2
        on m2.Company = m.Company
                and m2.Project = m.Project
                and m2.Milestone = 'Milestone 2'
                and m2.Completion = 100
```

edit should adress some ms access issues but cant test it on access honestly i don't see the benefit of the () around the first join

Comment: Hi Ufosnowcat. Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to execute the script (see the original post) but I got an error in MS Access (Syntax Error in FROM clause). What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: MS Access need parenthesises around each join - (t1 join t2 on ...) join t3 on ... etc.

Comment: Hi Arvo. I am struggling with that, still getting error messages. Would you be so kind and update that query as it should be? Thanks!!!

Comment: hmm been ages since i worked in access http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243855%28v=office.12%29.aspx has sone good tips possible we need to add the as for the alias

Comment: updated with () around the join and as for the aliasses, feel free to share if you get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

Add two `where` conditions, each one checking for the completion of a milestone:

```
from    Milestones m
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Milestones m1
        where   m1.Company = m.Company
                and m1.Project = m.Project
                and m1.Milestone = 'Milestone 1'
                and m1.Completion = 100
        )
        and exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Milestones m2
        where   m2.Company = m.Company
                and m2.Project = m.Project
                and m2.Milestone = 'Milestone 2'
                and m2.Completion = 100
        )
```

Comment: Hi Andomar, thanks for your suggestion! Tried to execute it in MS Access but even after 25 min I got no result. :-( Maybe it has to do with fact that this table has 60.000 lines and is extremely bad structure right? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there an index on `Milestones(Company, Project, Milestone)` ?  If not, add it.